# Silverlight toolkit datagrid remove cell vertical separator 

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

How can i remove cell vertical separators only in selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reaching it programmatically? You have to clear the BorderBrush and the Thickness properties of each cell. There is a rectangle called "RightBorderLine".

```
e.Cell.Presenter.ClearValue(DataGridCellPresenter.BorderBrushProperty);
e.Cell.Presenter.ClearValue(DataGridCellPresenter.BorderThicknessProperty);
```

If you try to override the Datagrid cell style it will affect only the selected datagrid cell (the one you clicked in when selecting the row).